# SQL Optimize Group By Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, query-optimization, large-data

I have a table here with following fields: 
Id, Name, kind. date

Data:

```
id     name     kind   date    
1      Thomas   1      2015-01-01    
2      Thomas   1      2015-01-01    
3      Thomas   2      2014-01-01    
4      Kevin    2      2014-01-01    
5      Kevin    2      2014-01-01    
5      Kevin    2      2014-01-01    
5      Kevin    2      2014-01-01    
6      Sasha    1      2014-01-01
```

I have an SQL statement like this:

```
Select name,kind,Count(*) AS RecordCount
from mytable 
group by kind, name
```

I want to know how many records there are for any name and kind. Expected results:

```
name     kind     count
Thomas   1        2
Thomas   2        1
Kevin    2        2
Sasha    1        4
```

The problem is that it is a big table, with more than 50 Million records.

Also I'd like to know the result within the last hour, last day, last week and so on, for which I need to add this `WHERE` clause this:

```
Select name,kind,Count(*) AS RecordCount      
from mytable 
WHERE Date > '2015-26-07'
group by kind, name
```

I use T-SQL with the SQL Server Management Studio. All of the relevant columns have a non clustered index and the primary key is a clustered index.

Does somebody have ideas how to make this faster?

Update:

The execution plan says:

- Select, Compute Scalar, Stream Aggregate, Sort, Parallelism: 0% costs.
- Hash Match (Partial Aggregate): 12%.
- Clustered Index Scan: 88%

Sorry, I forgot to check the SQL-statements.

Comment: first of all, neither of your sql statements are valid sql. the first `where` clause is missing any conditions and in the second example you have a `where` before the `from` and  second `where` clause without any conditions again.

Comment: For starters, you can add an index on the Date column or all columns in the where clause.

Comment: @FrankToast Have you checked your query's Execution Plan? Having a lot of indices is not always good, it could have adverse effects.

Comment: I have non clustered indices on the relevand columns and how can too many indices slow down the reading process (it is for writing, of course)

Comment: @FrankToast The keyword above was `not always`. You `KNOW` you have too many indices if your inserts/updates/deletes are too slow, and the index used for reading are not speeding things up enough to make up for it.

Comment: How far into the past is the "and so on"? If it's just few weeks and the 50 million is for several years then the date might help as an index. The percentages in the plan are just estimates, don't trust them too much. Look also at statistics io output.

Comment: Also, include the table definitions and indexes. It doesn't help if you say that all "relevant" indexes are there. If there is more tables involved or the actual need is more complex than this, please tell that too.

Answer (score 0):

50 million is just lot of rows
Not anything you can do to optimize that query that I can see

Possibly a composite index on kind, name
Or try name, kind
Or name only

I think the query optimizer is smart enough for this to not be a factor but but switch the group by to name, kind as name is more unique

If kind is not very unique (just 1 and 2) then you may be better off no index on that

I defrag the indexes you have

Answer (score -1):

To query the **last day** is no big deal because you already have a date column on witch you can put an index on.

For **last week** I would create a seperate date-table witch contains one row per day with columns id, date, week
You have to pre-calculate the week. And now if you want to query a specific week you can look in the date table, get the Dates and query only those dates from your tabele **mytable**
You should test if it is more performant to join the date columns or if you better put the id column in your myTable an join with id. For big tables id might be the better choice.

To query **last hour** you could add the column [hour] in myTable an query it in combination with the date